# Why is the parameter of the callback function in Svelte's `derived` function named with dollar sign?

Tags: javascript, svelte-store

In [Svelte tutorial about derived store](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/derived-stores), the name of the parameter of the callback function (, which itself is the second argument for the `derived` function) is prefixed with `$`. This is also the case in [the API documentation](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store#derived).

What's the meaning and effect of that dollar sign? I tried removing it from the example code (that is, from

```
($time) => Math.round(($time - start) / 1000)
```

to

```
time => Math.round((time - start) / 1000)
```

), and it also works. It feels to me that it's not supposed to be with dollar sign since this identifier seems to represent simply a parameter of the callback function, rather than a store object.

The example codes confusing me in the aforementioned links:

```
export const elapsed = derived(
    time,
    ($time) => Math.round(($time - start) / 1000)
//   ^^^^^                 ^^^^^ Why is it named like this?
);
```

```
const doubled = derived(a, ($a) => $a * 2);
//                          ^^     ^^ Why is it named like this?
```

Comment: No meaning. The "$" character can be used in any variable name.

Comment: I know that $ is legal JS identifier character. That's why I wonder why the Svelte documentation people specifically wrote it this way while they could have not, especially when they've addressed that _Any name beginning with $ is assumed to refer to a store value._ in [a previous tutorial](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/auto-subscriptions).

Comment: It looks like it's simply a code convention they use. The code examples you posted would still work if you did not use names like that.